# BufferStrategy Illegal State Exception

Tags: java, awt, illegalstateexception

After a few hours of trying to work this out I am stumped. I am somewhat new to Java and could use some help.

The Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component must have a valid peer
at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.createBuffers(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component$FlipBufferStrategy.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Canvas.createBufferStrategy(Unknown Source)
at com.mime.crystalnova.Display.render(Display.java:148)
at com.mime.crystalnova.Display.run(Display.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The error appears to be with this line of code here:

```
BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
if (bs == null) {
    createBufferStrategy(3);
    return;
}
```

The odd thing is that it gives me this error while debugging and then continues to run flawlessly. It works fine when launched via runnable jar file as well.

Comment: Don't you just love [heisenbugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)?

Comment: I figured it out. I simply called createBufferStrategy() too many times. :D

Comment: It might be helpful for future readers as well. Once you have completed solving this issue - you should post what the problem exactly was and how you managed to solve it. [as an answer - there is nothing wrong in answering your own question, as long as it fits and with good taste]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably got to do with the component not being visible yet at the time you call `createBufferStrategy()` (it's been a while). Try calling it at a later time.

The fact that your app continues to run probably means the component defaulted to a non-buffered strategy.